# Combine cells to MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

How to combine two cells using `MigLayout`?

I have two cells, as shown in the following code. I want to combine them, what do I have to do?

```
JPanel jPanelAccOil = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "0[]0", "0[]0"));
jPanelAccOil.add(new JPanelInAI(null, "",
    sistema.getGestorComunicacioOPC().getParametresOPCHyperG().getActuatorOilPressure()));
this.add(jPanelAccOil, "cell 2 3");

JPanel jPanelAccPneumatic = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "0[]0", "0[]0"));
jPanelAccPneumatic.add(new JPanelInAI(null, "",
    sistema.getGestorComunicacioOPC().getParametresOPCHyperG().getAccPneumaticPressure()));
this.add(jPanelAccPneumatic, "cell 3 3, wrap");
```

Comment: Be sure to review the preview of questions (below the post/edit area) before posting. That code was a mess! **General tips:** 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it is the first post I make on Stackoverflow.
In the future I will no longer make these mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use to span cells:

```
span 2
```

try this:

```
JPanel jPanelAccPneumatic = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "0[]0", "0[]0"));
jPanelAccPneumatic.add(new JPanelInAI(null, "",
    sistema.getGestorComunicacioOPC().getParametresOPCHyperG().getAccPneumaticPressure()));
this.add(jPanelAccPneumatic, "cell 3 3, span 2, wrap");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this will help me to finish my project, I'm new to using MigLayout.